# React DataTable not repopulating after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

So I am fetching an array of objects to fill my datatable, there is no issue with the fetching as i get the data I need in the format I need. I retrieve it from my redux store like so:

```
const contractorList = useSelector(state => state.contractorList)
const { loading, error, contractors } = contractorList
```

In my `useEffect` I check if the user is logged in, if so, I dispatch my action to get my data, map through it and push each object to my `data` array which is a state like so:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
```

Finally I have set the source of my DataTable to be my state array here:

```
<DataTable
    noHeader
    pagination
    selectableRowsNoSelectAll
    columns={columns}
    className='react-dataTable'
    paginationPerPage={25}
    sortIcon={<ChevronDown size={10} />}
    paginationDefaultPage={currentPage + 1}
    data={data}
/>
```

The Problem is as follows, if I visit the page initially, the data loads in the table fine, or if I navigate to this page from anywhere else in the app it seems to work grand. However if I manually refresh the page (so clicking the refresh button on my browser) I am met with "No Data to display" on my table. Almost as if the useEffect doesnt fire when I refresh. Anyone know why? I'm lost and I can't see it being an issue with my redux or useEffect as it works when navigating in the app.

Here is the useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
       if(userInfo ) {
            if(userInfo) {
                dispatch(listContractors())
            
                if(contractors) {
                    contractors.map(c => {
                        setData(data => [...data, {
                            action: <Link className='text-dark text-center' to={`/contractor/${c._id}`}><MoreHorizontal /></Link>,
                            psa_licence_no: c.psa_licence_no,
                            company: c.company,
                            trading_as: c.trading_as,
                            address_1: c.address_1,
                            address_2: c.address_2,
                            address_3: c.address_3,
                            county: c.county,
                            eircode: c.eircode,
                            contact_f_name: c.contact_f_name,
                            contact_s_name: c.contact_s_name,
                            office_tel_no: c.office_tel_no,
                            mobile_tel_no: c.mobile_tel_no,
                            sentinel_id: c.sentinel_id,
                            email: c.email,
                            intruder: c.intruder,
                            cctv: c.cctv,
                            guard_static: c.guard_static,
                            arc_intruder: c.arc_intruder,
                            arc_cctv: c.arc_cctv,
                            issue_date: c.issue_date,
                            expiry_date: c.expiry_date,
                            psa_date_added: c.psa_date_added,
                            psa_date_updated: c.psa_date_updated,
                            psa_date_removed: c.psa_date_removed
                        }])
                    })
                }
            }
       } else {
           history.push('/login')
       }
    }, [dispatch, userInfo, history, successCreate])
```

If I add `contractors` to the list of dependencies, then it created an infinite loop of doing the `listContractors` action

Comment: Looks like initially the `userInfo` is not evaluated to `true` so the `if(userInfo) {` prevents the rest of the code from running. How/where/when do you update the `userInfo` ?

Comment: The problem persists even if I have no if statement checking the userInfo

Comment: You do `dispatch(listContractors())`. Is that fired ? what does it do. You then do `contractors.map` but if the `contractors` is populated by the result of `listContractors` then it will not be ready yet. Then you do `push` in the `data` instead of `setData`. In general there seem to be a series of problems in your code. You should post a full example that reproduces the problem so we can see it in action and offer help.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli If I replicate the error by refreshing the page and seeing no data displayed, the contractors have still been fetched and I can see them in my redux dev tools. It returns an array of objects. Maybe the error is your second point and I am not sure how to use setData when it is initially an empty array. The reason I need to map through them is to add further data to each object like buttons etc

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I have altered my code so now I am changing the data using `setData` I have updated it in the question also, the problem is still happening though, maybe it is the fact that the contractors isnt ready as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break your useEffect to two since they handle different parts of your code, one to dispatch a fetch and the other to massage the data when received.

```js
// this will dispatch the listContractors action when the userInfo changes
useEffect(() => {
  if (userInfo) {
    dispatch(listContractors())
  } else {
    history.push('/login')
  }
}, [userInfo, history])

// this will update the data when contractors is changed
useEffect(() => {
  if (contractors) {
    const transformedContractors = contractors.map(contractor => ({
      ...contractor, // used this to avoid the one-by-one hand written copy.
      action: <Link className='text-dark text-center' to={`/contractor/${c._id}`}><MoreHorizontal /></Link>
    }));
    setData(transformedContractors);
  }
}, [contractors]);
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much! I've never seen useEffect being used like that before, thanks for teaching me this. Also I didn't think to use `...contractor` when creating the new object, thanks so much

Comment: @BranOIE glad to help